# Compatibility of Android sdk tools, platforms, platform-tools and build-tools

Tags: cordova, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I am using android-sdk on a linux machine to build a cordova project for android. I have everything working fine but I want to understand in more detail how different sdk tools are working.
Current versions of tools installed are `./sdkmanager --list`

```
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...             
  Path                        | Version | Description                    | Location                    
  -------                     | ------- | -------                        | -------                     
  build-tools;25.0.3          | 25.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3 | build-tools/25.0.3/         
  emulator                    | 26.1.4  | Android Emulator               | emulator/                   
  extras;android;m2repository | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository     | extras/android/m2repository/
  extras;google;m2repository  | 58      | Google Repository              | extras/google/m2repository/ 
  patcher;v4                  | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4/                 
  platform-tools              | 26.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/             
  platforms;android-19        | 4       | Android SDK Platform 19        | platforms/android-19/       
  platforms;android-25        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25        | platforms/android-25/       
  platforms;android-26        | 2       | Android SDK Platform 26        | platforms/android-26/       
  tools                       | 26.1.1  | Android SDK Tools              | tools/
```

After reading and searching for the different sdk-components I am still not clear on build-tools, platform-tools, platforms and tools.
I have not specified any sdkVersion in my configuration but still the target is always set is Android-25. 
Why isn't it set to the highest available i.e. Android-26 by default.

Currently I have `build-tools 25.0.3`, `platform-tools 26.0.2` and `sdk-tools as 26.1.1` and when I add the android platform to my project I get `Android target: android-25`.
None of these version numbers coincide. So I am confused how is my project being built and which devices will it be compatible with.